# Add an asterisk to the output

Tags: python

I have recently started learning Python and I have a countdown timer. It works fine but I wanted to add an asterisk to the output.

A recreation of the output is:

```
Countdown timer: How many seconds? 4          
4****   
3***   
2**   
1*  
Blast off
```

So far I have:

```
import time

countDown = input('Countdown Timer: How many seconds?')

for i in range (int(countDown), 0, -1):
    print (i)
    time.sleep(1)
print ('BLAST OFF')
```

Comment: I couldn't find anything on youtube or any other website like stack overflow

Comment: you can experiment with something like `print(str(i) + '*'*i`) ... this will convert the number i to a string and add '*' i times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will work:

```
import time

countDown = input('Countdown Timer: How many seconds?')

for i in range (int(countDown), 0, -1):
    print(i*'*') # This will print i number of '*'s
    time.sleep(1)
print ('BLAST OFF')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `*` while printing with numbers.

```
import time

countDown = input('Countdown Timer: How many seconds?')

for i in range (int(countDown), 0, -1):
    print (i,"*"*(i))
    time.sleep(1)
print ('BLAST OFF')
```

Or `print str(i)+"*"*(i)` - without space after the number.

Comment: This is only valid Python 2. OP is likely on Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for the desired output

```
import time
countDown = input('Countdown Timer: How many seconds?')

for i in range (int(countDown), 0, -1):
  print (i), 
  print ('*' * i) 
  time.sleep(1)
print ('BLAST OFF')
```

Comment: This only works for Python 2, OP is likely on Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code more flexible by defining it as a function.

**What is a funtion?**
Function is an organised block of code which provides modularity so that the code can be reused.

Say, a function blastOff() is defined. We can call this function with any value of countdown, whether 4 or 10 or 20, passed as an argument of a function within the parenthesis. And we can do this without having to write the code again and again.

```
import time
def blastOff(n):
    """Returns "Blast Off" after a reverse countdown of n"""
    for i in reversed(range(1, n + 1)): # iterate over a reversed range
        print(i, i * "*") # multiply "*" by the ith number of the range.
        time.sleep(1) # sleep for a second before looping over the next number in the range.
    return "BLAST OFF"

blastOff(4)

4 ****
3 ***
2 **
1 *
Out: 'BLAST OFF'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3 then try this code

```
import time
countDown = input('Countdown Timer: How many seconds?')

for i in range (int(countDown), 0, -1):
  print(i, end=" ")
  print ('*' * i) 
  time.sleep(1)
print ('BLAST OFF')
```